# Asus laptop LCD screen broken (freezing, flickering, moving)

Tags: laptop, display, lcd

This is [a video of my Asus x51l](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XnsQWZrAMQk).

The main problem is just the freezing picture, and the lines on LCD!
Is it better to take it to computer service, or is it easy to fix it at home?

It is freezing all the time (just the picture is freezing), then if I move a litle up and down it is OK.. but the contact is very bad.

How to fix it?

Comment: Has your laptop recently had any incidents that involve floors and falling down? Joke aside: Have you still got warranty on it?

Comment: yes it drop down on flor, to late for warranty :)

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to run another operating system to see if it is a software or hardware issue. Lines on the screen usually means a bad LCD screen... but you say the picture is freezing.

Freezing is usally a sign of a bad operating system. Download Ubuntu and run a live CD. If everything works then you should try reinstalling a fresh copy of Windows.